# Is there any way to use a bigger batch size without reducing model complexity? (convolutional neural network)

Tags: tensorflow, resources, conv-neural-network

I'm struggling to train a convolutional neural network inspired by VGG-16 model:

```
Input image: 70x70 pixels cropped face
2 x cov-3 (1, 64), (64, 64)
max_pooling
dropout (keep_rate = 0.75)
2 x conv-3 (64, 128), (128, 128)
max_pooling
dropout (keep_rate = 0.75)
2 X conv-3 (128, 256), (256, 256)
1 X conv-3 (256, 256)
max_pooling
dropout (keep_rate = 0.75)
2 X conv-3 (256, 512), (512, 512)
1 X conv-3 (512, 512)
max_pooling
dropout (keep_rate = 0.75)
fully_connected 3*3*512 - output 2048
dropout (keep_rate = 0.75)
fully_connected 2048 - output 128
```

**The problem is I can't use more that 40 images/mini-batch**, because they don't fit into memory.
I'm using tensorflow as framework.
This is the error I get:

```
ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[70,18,18,256]
     [[Node: siamese/Conv2D_32 = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](siamese/Relu_33, siamese/w_conv3_3/read)]]
     [[Node: siamese/l2_normalize_2/_27 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_3157_siamese/l2_normalize_2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

**Is there any way I could use a larger mini-batch size?** Maybe accumulate the gradient somehow and then propagate it?

My RAM details:

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7911        1786        1963          79        4161        5705
Swap:          8119           0        8119
```

Comment: Do you have a way to reproduce your training? I'm working on putting some techniques from my [talk](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/blob/master/tensorflow-memory-talk.pdf) into an easier to use package

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I'm feeding triplets to the network (generated offline using the training images from Labeled Faces in the Wild website) - I cropped them first using dlib so there would be no background. So I use an anchor image (photo of Jhon), a positive image (other photo of Jhon) and a negative image (photo of someone else) - and triplet loss as cost function

Comment: I meant is there an easy recipe to reproduce your OOM error (maybe for a related network)